# flutter- TextFiled suffix Icon was not working when voice over is switched ON

Tags: flutter, accessibility, voiceover, flutter-textformfield

In my application We have a Close icon at the end of the Textfield.

closeIcon was added in textField's suffix icon. So it is not read out by the voice over and not functioning as expected.  (Overriding by textfield's semantic widget) Without voiceOver it is working fine. We have added this closeIcon to textfield SuffixIcon. (It must be like this). Anyone please help me how closeIcon will work with voiceOver.

code:

child:

```
TextField(
                    key: widget.inputKey,
                    textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
                    onEditingComplete: widget.onEditCompleted,
                    style: style.inputStyle.textStyle,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      hintText: widget.hint,
                      errorStyle: style.errorStyle.textStyle,
                      hintStyle: style.hintStyle.textStyle,
                      prefixStyle: style.prefixStyle.textStyle,
                      suffixStyle: style.suffixStyle.textStyle,
                      counterStyle: style.counterStyle.textStyle,
                      suffixIconConstraints: context.theme.getIconStyle(formInputPrefixIconStyleId).constraints,
                      suffixIcon: _suffixIcon(context),
                      prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 8, minHeight: 8),
                      prefixIcon: widget.textFieldPrefix != null ? _fieldPrefix(style) : null,
                      border: _getBorderStyle(style),
                      focusedBorder: _getFocusedBorderStyle(style),
                      enabledBorder: _getEnabledBorderStyle(style),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      setState(() {
                        _shouldShowClearIcon = text.isNotEmpty;
                      });
                      widget.onChanged.call(text);
                    },
                    focusNode: widget.focusNode,
                    controller: widget.controller,
                    showCursor: true,
                    keyboardAppearance: style.keyboardAppearance,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: _hasError(),
                child: AppFieldError(
                  key: const Key('bottomErrorContainer'),
                  errorText: widget.alertMessage,
                  style: context.theme
                      .getContainerStyle(widget.showWarning ? formWarningContainerStyleId : formErrorContainerStyleId),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }




 Widget _suffixIcon(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.hasShowSuccess) {
      return _successIcon(context);
    }

    if (_shouldShowClearIcon && widget.isEnabled) {
      return _clearIcon(context);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: I came across the same issue. Suppose the semantics of the text input field and the icon are conflicting. Is there even a quick solution for this or the solution is to build a custom widget? I am afraid that even doing so, it will not look like the icon is in the textfield, which is the design in this case.